# Locust failed to fire events when running as lib

Tags: python, locust

The following code is from the [tutorial](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/use_as_lib.py). I just added some codes to fire the `test_start` event(not sure if I fire it in the right place ?) and listen to both `init` and `test_start` events.

```
import gevent
from locust import HttpUser, task, events
from locust.env import Environment
from locust.stats import stats_printer, stats_history
from locust.log import setup_logging

setup_logging("INFO", None)


class MyUser(HttpUser):
    host = "https://docs.locust.io"

    @task
    def t(self):
        self.client.get("/")

    @events.init.add_listener
    def on_locust_init(**kwargs):
        print("on locust init ...")


    @events.test_start.add_listener
    def on_test_start(**kwargs):
        print("on test start ...")


# setup Environment and Runner
env = Environment(user_classes=[MyUser])
runner = env.create_local_runner()

# start a WebUI instance
web_ui = env.create_web_ui("127.0.0.1", 8089)

# execute init event handlers (only really needed if you have registered any)
env.events.init.fire(environment=env, runner=runner, web_ui=web_ui)

# start a greenlet that periodically outputs the current stats
gevent.spawn(stats_printer(env.stats))

# start a greenlet that save current stats to history
gevent.spawn(stats_history, env.runner)

# start the test
runner.start(1, spawn_rate=1)

# execute test_start event handlers (only really needed if you have registered any)
env.events.test_start.fire(environment=env, runner=runner, web_ui=web_ui)

# in 10 seconds stop the runner
gevent.spawn_later(10, lambda: runner.quit())

# wait for the greenlets
runner.greenlet.join()

# stop the web server for good measures
web_ui.stop()
```

When I ran it as a library (e.g. `python use_as_lib.py`), the two messages in MyUser didn't print. But if I remove those run-as-lib codes, and run it as tool (e.g. `locust -f use_as_lib.py --headless -u 1 -r 1 -t=10s`), messages been printed in the console. Seems I missed anything...

Here's my locust version.

```
locust 2.13.0 from /Users/myuser/workspace/tmp/try_python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust (python 3.8.12)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code a bit, I need to add [locust.events](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/46fac3e9840873ec689156f0da4cd354ab6119be/locust/main.py#L186) when initialize the Environment().

```
# ...
env = Environment(user_classes=[MyUser], events=events)
```

I think the use_as_lib example need to be updated.

Comment: I agree! Could I bother you to make a PR?

Comment: @Cyberwiz, PR #2285, please take a look : )